# Is there a way to ECHO inside a php variable?

Tags: php

I am getting a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)" whenever i try and echo another variable inside a variable like this:

```
$content=. '<p>Paragraph '.echo $variable.' here</p> ';
```

Comment: Remove the echo. Echo is to send it to the screen, and what you're trying to attempt here is concatenate a string into a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$content .= '<p>Paragraph '.$variable.' here</p> ';
echo $content;
```

It should be like this. (`.`) dot should be before `=` and `echo` should not be inside the content